# How do I pass database credentials as environment variables from docker-compose to Symfony to the Doctrine yaml file?

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose, doctrine-orm

I have a docker env set up with Symfony (5.x) & MariaDB - the `docker-compose.yaml` file contains the db configuration env variables.

The `.env.local` file in the Symfony app uses the configuration variables from the `docker-compose` file to build out the `DATABASE_URL` - the url value appears as expected in the `bin/console debug:container --env-vars` command within the container.

The `doctrine.yaml` file for the Symfony app uses `url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'` - this does *not* appear to be working as expected, as the app is throwing a 500 error on the front end saying it cannot connect to the db.

Dumping the `$_ENV` and `$params` variables from the `Connection` Doctrine class shows the `$_ENV` vars correctly, but the passed `$params` value contains the default `pdo_mysql` protocol and none of the vars from the `docker-composer.yaml` file.

If I hardcode the distinct values to the `doctrine.yaml` `dbal` fields (`user`, `host` etc) the app works as expected.

I'm fairly new to Symfony, so it's highly likely that I'm missing something pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer you're looking for, but since you are new to Symfony. Its important to understand this :
you should not use simple env var to store your database url but symfony secret system.

Read this for setup and understand how it work.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/secrets.html

In your case it would be

```
php bin/console secrets:set DATABASE_URL
```

Then it will asked you to enter the value.

Then you can easily register different value for each env.

```
php bin/console secrets:set DATABASE_URL --env=prod
```

Will store a different value for prod env.

The key point is to understand this :

> You should not be able to find any sensitive information inside your codebase. No password, no api key, no hashed signature.

Symfony secret are made for this reason.
In local you can check their value easily because you can do

```
bin/console secrets:list --reveal
```

But this `--reveal` require to have decrypt.private.php file in local **WHICH SHOULD NOT BE PUSHED TO GIT FOR TEST AND PROD ENV SECRETS**
You have one decrypt file for each env.

Then, manually upload this file to your test / prod server and when you deploy your app you can do

```
secrets:decrypt-to-local --force
```

And

```
composer dump-env prod (for example)
```

Then, all secret will be available as env var. Excactly the same way than if you put it directly inside .env file but in a protected way.

Answer (score 0):

Please set all values in the .env file and copy this environment file into a docker container. Please add this line to your docker file.
`COPY ./.env /var/www/html/application/.env`

Here the first path is local and application/.env is the docker container path. Please change accordingly.